# Connect 2 ubuntu computers into a LAN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, connection

I've got two computers both running Ubuntu and i want to connect them into a LAN so i can ssh from the one into the another - i know how to do the ssh configuration part, i just don't know how to connect them - i put the cable but nothing happened.

Please tell me what needs to be done.

Comment: Do you have a router?

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect the computers together without a switch or hub, you will need a crossover cable.  You should be able to get one at your local electronics parts house.

Comment: If you are going to use a crossover cable or a hub, you'll need to assign static IP addresses to each computer, because usually when you hook two machines up directly there is no DHCP server to hand out addresses.

Comment: Modern NICs will work with a simple cable too when being directly connected, but the advice about getting a crossover is wise and safe.

Comment: Good points both. I presumed the OP would know about assigning IPs due to his statement about SSH configurations. Also, from my experience with Linux users, most are utilizing older equipment that may or may not have more modern NICs.